# Using bought .cer ssl certificate with express node

Tags: node.js, express, https

For my work I have to install an https node server. I have checked on how to isntall it and found solutions for openssl and self signed certificates.
But my client gave me a bought certificate with just a *.cer file, nothing else.

I can't find how to install it with a nodejs app because I do not have a private key file because the certificate comes from a certificate authority.

Should I just do something like this ?

```
var httpsOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/file/cert.cer')
};
```

Can someone help with it ?

Comment: Your server certificate needs a private key in order to work.

Comment: @JoshLee Here is what my client said when I asked him for a private key.
 "We can't have the private keys of a certificate authority
This kind of file can only be generated for a self-signed certificate". So I am a bit stuck right now

Comment: Your client should have retained the private key from the keypair he generated when he created the Certificate Signing Request (CSR) that he then sent to his CA. That's the private key you need now. Read the [Wikipedia page on CSRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) to see how that procedure goes. If he doesn't still have that original private key then his nice new certificate is useless. BTW, this isn't really a programming question. It would be a better fit on the [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) site.

Comment: @ottomeister Thank you for your answer ! I will contact my client and see how to handle all this.
I tought I missed something on the documentation that why I posted on "programming"